# How can I fix my where clause in SAS

Tags: date, sas

I have a table is SAS say `t` looking like this

```
A           B                   C       D
--------------------------------------------------------------
VOLUME      172631922966528     IMPLIED 2012-10-04
VOLUME      173731441803264     IMPLIED 2012-10-04
PRIX_VOLUME 189124634214400     IMPLIED 2012-10-04
PRIX_VOLUME 123153895784448     IMPLIED 2012-10-04
VOLUME      266090408574976     IMPLIED 2012-10-04
VOLUME      119855364243456     IMPLIED 2012-10-04
```

The column D is a `Date` (format `yymmdd10`) colume and I have a macrovarible `date0` that is worth `2012-10-04` I am trying to do a trivial data-step

```
data test;
    set t (where=(A eq "VOLUME" and D eq &date0.));
run;
```

but this is not working

Can you help fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

That is because when the macro variable is processed, you get:

```
data test;
    set t (where=(A eq "VOLUME" and D eq 2012-10-04));
run;
```

Which SAS will resolve as:
    data test;
        set t (where=(A eq "VOLUME" and D eq 1998));
    run;
Because it sees math instead of a date.
You need to make clear to SAS that:
 1. it is not algebra.
 2. it should read it as a date.

To make it read it as a string, add quotes. To make clear that the string represents a date, append a d after the quotes:

```
data test;
    set t (where=(A eq "VOLUME" and D eq "&date0."d));
run;
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: In fact it does the trick if the macrovariable is the number under 2012-10-04... not if it is still 2012-10-04, but it is good enough for me